# calculating the minimum, mean, and maximum values of the expanding window in a time series dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, time-series

I found the following code for my task which I would need to compute mean,min,max of a timeseries dataframe up to each time step.
for instance the value for time step 10 should include all the information from time step 0 to time step 10.
The following code seems to be working for a series of data, I was wondering if there exists a pythonic way to do that for a dataframe

```
from pandas import DataFrame
from pandas import concat
series = read_csv('daily-min-temperatures.csv', header=0, index_col=0)
temps = DataFrame(series.values)
window = temps.expanding()
dataframe = concat([window.min(), window.mean(), window.max(), temps.shift(-1)], axis=1)
dataframe.columns = ['min', 'mean', 'max', 't+1']
print(dataframe.head(5))
```

Comment: Can you provide the output of `print(series.head(10).to_dict())`, please. Thanks.

Comment: @Corralien here is the link to the dataset

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/daily-min-temperatures.csv

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('daily-min-temperatures.csv', header=0, index_col=0)
out = df['Temp'].expanding().agg(['min', 'mean', 'max']) \
                .assign(**{'t+1': df['Temp'].shift(-1)})
```

Output:

```
>>> out
             min       mean   max   t+1
Date                                   
1981-01-01  20.7  20.700000  20.7  17.9
1981-01-02  17.9  19.300000  20.7  18.8
1981-01-03  17.9  19.133333  20.7  14.6
1981-01-04  14.6  18.000000  20.7  15.8
1981-01-05  14.6  17.560000  20.7  15.8
...          ...        ...   ...   ...
1990-12-27   0.0  11.174712  26.3  13.6
1990-12-28   0.0  11.175377  26.3  13.5
1990-12-29   0.0  11.176014  26.3  15.7
1990-12-30   0.0  11.177254  26.3  13.0
1990-12-31   0.0  11.177753  26.3   NaN

[3650 rows x 4 columns]
```